# React / Redux: Should containers have any knowledge of state structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This [tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) by Dan Abramov suggests that the advantage to using selectors that act on global state (rather than a slice of state) is that they allow containers to be decoupled from knowledge of the state structure.

If that's the case, shouldn't we also avoid directly mapping state values to props, and use selectors instead? Otherwise, our containers must still know about where those values exist in the state tree.

To illustrate using an example...

*Directly maps a nested state value to a prop:*

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isModalVisible: state.modal.isVisible,
});
```

**VS**

*Has no knowledge of state structure. Gets value using `isModalVisible()` selector:*

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isModalVisible: isModalVisible(state),
});
```

However, the problem with the latter approach is that for each value in the state tree, we have to write a selector. This seems like a lot of boilerplate code just to select a simple value. Is this considered best practice?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The second approach is preferred and it's not direct mapping. Once a specific value mapped to props, we can keep using it from then on, e.g. `this.props.isModalVisible` and we don't need to care about the state tree. Why need the container know the tree structure then?

Comment: But using the second approach we have to write selectors for **all** values in the state tree, even if they're not derived data. I haven't seen this suggested as the *preferred* approach.

Comment: That's the concept behind selectors. Imagine you have a highly nested state tree, writing a selector once and you can use it anywhere without digging into the tree. Also, you might modify the tree structure from time to time, then you just need to modify selectors accordingly instead of modifying every component. That's why it's recommended to write selectors for all values in the tree.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that if you have a simple value somewhere in the state tree, you have to write a selector for it at the slice level, then write another selector for it at the global level that delegates to the slice-level selector, and then import that global selector into your container component... just to get a simple, non-derived value from state. Does this not seem like a massive amount of overhead, especially if you have to do it for all state values?

Comment: ...not to mention the testing overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer for your question is: "it depends"

**Do you have a tiny app?**

Maybe avoid using redux at all and stick to react components state.

[**You Might Not Need Redux**](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)

**Do you have a small app?**

Writing a bunch of selectors is a lot of boilerplate just like you said. Avoid writing them and stick to simply mapping, using `mapStateToProps`.

**Medium to large apps?**

This is where selectors and memoized selectors pay-off. You'll find yourself checking if modals is visible in many components. Currently in your state modal is under `state.modal.visible`. But tomorrow a modal might be a part of a parent modal, you'll have to change all mapping in all your components to `state.parentModal.modal.visible`. You can see how this can turn badly right?

**The pros of selectors:**

- Hides complexity when working in a team.
- Changing your state means **only** modifying your selector function.
- Avoid writing filters and reducing lists on each `mapPropsToState` function.

**Pros of Memoized selectors:**

- Performance.

**Cons**

- Boilerplate code and slower to get started.
- Additional libraries.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Given that I'm working on a large app, I guess the only lingering problem is the sheer volume of selectors that are going to live in the global reducer file, which will make naming them difficult.

Comment: @PatrickIvers There is not need to work with a global reducer file, reducers should be broken down to smaller reducers. I highly advice you to check this react-tetris project and his store/reducers structure: https://github.com/chvin/react-tetris. He may went a little overboard but it's a nice example how to split reducers. It'll force you to split you selectors and actions.

Comment: They are broken down. I'm just referring to the file that contains the call to `combineReducers()`. I felt this was the appropriate place to put global selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Responding to your last comment, yes, it's recommended to write selectors for all values in the tree, even for simple, non-derived value.

Several reasons to do so:

1. As I mentioned in the comments, once you are using selectors for all the values, you can modify the tree structure as you like and then you only need to modify selectors accordingly. Otherwise you and your co-developer will have to modify every direct mapping mannually, even it's non-derived data.
2. Decoupling values between different levels in the tree. Like you said, when you have a global-level selector depends on a slice-level selector, e.g. `price` inside `product`. When you put product onto somewhere else in the tree, just modify the `product` selector, and all you global-level selector `price` will still be fine. I'm not sure Dan mentioned in his tutorial, check this library [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). It shows the idea between levels.
3. Efficiency when fetching computed data.

Ofc if you are doing a small project or retrieving simple non-derived values from the tree, you can use direct mapping. But keep in mind applying selectors widely makes your code **scalable**.

Answer (score 3):

`mapStateToProps` *is* the selector. You don't need to write a separate function for `isModalVisible` necessarily. The idea is `mapStateToProps` is the only function that needs to know the structure of the global state. You can break down that function if you want, especially as the subs-selectors get more complex, but if all you're doing is selecting a simple value, there's no need to do so.

As a result, the container component *doesn't know the state structure*. It just knows the structure of the value returned by `mapStateToProps`. Your two examples are functionally equivalent, as it relates to the question "Should containers know the state structure?". Because in both cases, the answer is "They don't."

Comment: But that still leaves the problem of having to change every `mapStateToProps` function (which could be *many* in a large application) if the value that is being mapped changes its location in the state tree.

Comment: Sure; if your application is that large, then you need to break it down into smaller functions that do less. All I'm saying is that simply by using `mapStateToProps`, you've decoupled the (React) container component from needing to know anything about the structure of the store.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix the local state with the global state (redux store). You can have both on a component but the local state should not depend on global state.

This is due to the following reasons:

- It will be hard to test the component
- It is a source of more bugs
- It will need to keep sync with global state